# How to properly implement a kerning generated code

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, kerning

I have a situation trying to implement into the `<header>`, a logotext using kerning technique, with this simple but very handy [tool](http://rewdy.com/tools-files/kerning-tool.htm) made by Mr.Andrew (special thanks).

Before the modification, I had this `<header>` section in `header.php`:

```
...
        <!-- Start Header -->

        <header class="header row no-padding <?php echo $header_style; ?>" data-equal=">.columns" role="banner">

            <div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo<?php if ($header_style == 'style1') { ?> show-for-large-up<?php } ?>">

                <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { ?>

                    <a class="logotext" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"

                    title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"

                    rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>

                    </a>

                <?php } ?>

            </div>

            <?php if ($header_style != 'style2') { ?>

            <div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo">

                <?php if ($header_style == 'style1') { ?>

                    <a class="logotext" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"

                    title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"

                    rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>

                    </a>

                <?php } ?>

            </div>

            <?php } ?>

            <div class="small-5 <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { echo 'medium-8'; } else { echo 'medium-4';} ?> columns menu-holder">

                <?php $full_menu_true = ($menu_mobile_toggle_view == 'style2' && $header_style == 'style2');?>

                <?php if ($full_menu_true) { ?>

                    <nav id="full-menu" role="navigation">

                        <?php if ($page_menu) { ?>

                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $page_menu, 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'full-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown  ) ); ?>

                        <?php } else  if(has_nav_menu('nav-menu')) { ?>

                          <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'nav-menu', 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'full-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown ) ); ?>

                        <?php } else { ?>

                            <ul class="full-menu">

                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url().'nav-menus.php'; ?>">Please assign a menu from Appearance -> Menus</a></li>

                            </ul>

                        <?php } ?>

                    </nav>

                <?php } ?>

                <?php if ($header_search != 'off') { do_action( 'thb_quick_search' ); } ?>

                <?php if ($header_cart != 'off') { do_action( 'thb_quick_cart' ); } ?>

                <a href="#" data-target="open-menu" class="mobile-toggle<?php if (!$full_menu_true) { ?> always<?php } ?>">

                    <div>

                        <span></span><span></span><span></span>

                    </div>

                </a>

            </div>

        </header>

        <!-- End Header -->
...
```

using the generated kerning `code`, I was tried (and please correct me if it's a bad approach for `php` coding):

```
...
        <!-- Start Header -->
    <header class="header row no-padding <?php echo $header_style; ?>" data-equal=">.columns" role="banner">                        
        <div class="row max_width ">
            <div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo<?php if ($header_style == 'style1') { ?> show-for-large-up<?php } ?>">
                <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { ?>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -18px;">n</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -17px;">e</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -18.5px;">u</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -13px;">e</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -23.5px;">g</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -7px;">r</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -19px;">i</span>
                    <span class="logotext">d</span>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>          
        </div>              
                <?php if ($header_style != 'style2') { ?>                       
        <div class="row max_width ">            
            <div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo">
                <?php if ($header_style == 'style1') { ?>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -18px;">n</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -17px;">e</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -18.5px;">u</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -13px;">e</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -23.5px;">g</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -7px;">r</span>
                    <span class="logotext" style="letter-spacing: -19px;">i</span>
                    <span class="logotext">d</span>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>          
        </div>  
    <?php } ?>                      
        <div class="row max_width ">        
            <div class="small-5 <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { echo 'medium-8'; } else { echo 'medium-4';} ?> columns menu-holder">
                <?php $full_menu_true = ($menu_mobile_toggle_view == 'style2' && $header_style == 'style2');?>
                <?php if ($full_menu_true) { ?>
                    <nav id="full-menu" role="navigation">
                        <?php if ($page_menu) { ?>
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $page_menu, 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'full-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown  ) ); ?>
                        <?php } else  if(has_nav_menu('nav-menu')) { ?>
                          <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'nav-menu', 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'full-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown ) ); ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <ul class="full-menu">
                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url().'nav-menus.php'; ?>">Please assign a menu from Appearance -> Menus</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </nav>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($header_search != 'off') { do_action( 'thb_quick_search' ); } ?>
                <?php if ($header_cart != 'off') { do_action( 'thb_quick_cart' ); } ?>
                <a href="#" data-target="open-menu" class="mobile-toggle<?php if (!$full_menu_true) { ?> always<?php } ?>">
                    <div>
                        <span></span><span></span><span></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>          
        </div>  
    </header>
    <!-- End Header -->
...
```

Now, not so sure why, [the result](http://goo.gl/9Xz6GM) looks as it should in Chrome but in IE11/Firefox the letters are scrambled somehow in vertical position.

Any thoughts?

LE: with all due respect, I have to reconsider the answer validation because the sugestion doesn't help to have a solution properly implemented, [It looks ok](http://goo.gl/9Xz6GM) in Chrome but in IE/Firefox the Kerning values (the main subject of this question) it doesn't have any effect.

Hope you don't mind guys, but I still need an answer to close this question having the right solution for me and other people that will deal with this issue in the future. If I didn't understand right the implementation steps, it will be ok to have an answer more specific with real examples, I'm not lazy, just a pure noob (I already mentioned in my posts).Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using an URL shortener for your site? What is wrong with using your site?

Comment: I was thinking of keeping the search engines results - like Google, Bing etc - clean, not pointing to the forum discussions (is that ok ?) :)

Comment: Forum? What forum? Anyway, the code is in a div with a width of 33.333% for class `medium-4` and also 58.333% for class `small-7` as well as 100% for class `columns`; maybe that confuses the browsers.

Comment: Forums generally speaking. thank you for your sugestion :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `.logo` div is constrained to 33% width because it also has the `.medium-4` class.

IE and Firefox are actually handling this correctly. For whatever reason, chrome is letting the content exceed the specified width of the container; this has something to do with the `display` attribute for `.logo` being set to `table`.

The solution is to remove the `medium-4` (and `small-7`) classes and either use the correct scaffolding classes or define the width in your CSS.

Comment: thank you for your sugestion too.Let me try that, and I'll come back with the validation is that ok? not so sure If I can replace the `medium-4`/`small-7` classes as long as they are part of the theme core code, but I'll try ...

Comment: If you cannot remove the classes from the logo div, just override the width in your CSS `.header .logo { width: auto; }`

Comment: If you really can't change the classes, the only thing to it is make a new style rule with a more specific selector, say `.small-7.medium-4.colums {width:whatever}` or, give the div a style attribute

Comment: @MrLister You shouldn't adjust the width of your scaffolding classes unless you want the change to be universal. It's better to target the element and override the width.

Comment: @mtinsley your solution it works like a charm ... thank you. How can we share the validation? :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What do you mean by share the validation? If you mean how do you indicate that the solution is valid, then you would just mark it as accepted.

Comment: I was kidding and pretty confused because was not so sure who said the right answer :) I really appreciate it. Can I make somehow to center this, no matter how much the window will expand? what is your best approach from your point of wiew please?

Comment: If you remove the float from the logo and set it to full width, the text should center. You'll also need to remove the left padding otherwise it won't align right.

Comment: I figured out in the end somehow using only the `.header .logo {width: auto;}` + `row max_width` + `padding` because I need fine tunning specially on the menu butons positions.The problem that occurs is regarding the main subject (kerning) that it looks different in Chrome (the default browser) vs. IE/Firefox. Can I fix that ?

Comment: @typo_78 This question has turned into a bit of a moving target. You should reformulate it, specify exactly what you want, and create a new question. SO's QA style isn't meant for progressively working through problems.

Comment: @mtinsley sorry if I was unclear but as the title said, the main goal is to have in the end the kerning code applied, in order to be visible in IE/Firefox like we have it in Chrome (letters are close to each other). With your agreement I'll delete / reformulate the question. Your  `.header .logo {width: auto;}` solution was good to unscramble the letters and to show them in line but the kerning is it still missing in Firefox/IE. thank you for understanding.